# R, how can I sum the values of a variable for unique id-numbers in another variable

Tags: r, sum, dataset

I am using R. I have a dataset "df", with the columns {"id-number", "A"}. How can I sum the values in A for unqiue id-numbers?. That means, lets say the id-number have the values {1,1,2,2,3,3} and the corresponding A column has the values {10,10,40,40,30,30}. I want R to do 10+40+30. This question is probably a duplicate, but I couldn't find its duplicate.

Comment: Using `dplyr`: `df %>% distinct(id-number, A) %>% summarize(A = sum(A))` Note that the `-` in the variable `id-number` is going to cause a problem, best to rename it to `id` or whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you. How to add condintions to this, for example if I only want to sum where          A<50

Comment: `df %>% distinct(id-number, A) %>% filter(A < 50) %> summarize(A = sum(A))`

Comment: Try putting back ticks around `id-number`